# Serialize only specific attributes using Writes trait with unapply

Tags: json, scala, serialization, playframework

Lets imagine I have a case class like this:

```
case class Product(ean: Long, name: String, description: String)
```

and I want so serialize objects of this class to Json, I can implement the Writes trait like this:

```
implicit val productWrites: Writes[Product] = (
  (JsPath \ "ean").write[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "description").write[String]
)(unlift(Product.unapply))
```

This works fine if I want to serialize all the attributes of the object. Now lets say I don't want to serialize the `ean`. I tried something like this:

```
implicit val productWrites: Writes[Product] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "description").write[String]
)(unlift(Product.unapply))
```

This doesn't seem to work since one needs to use all the fields/attributes that the unapply method returns.

Is there a way to make the second serialization method work with only the attributes that I want to serialize or do I have to use something like this:

```
implicit object ProductWrites extends Writes[Product] {
  def writes(p: Product) = Json.obj(
    "name" -> Json.toJson(p.name),
    "description" -> Json.toJson(p.description)
  )
}
```

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unlift(Product.unapply)` has a type `Product => (Long, String, String)`.

In this case, the argument should have a type `Product => (String, String)`. You can write a function literal like following.

```
implicit val productWrites: Writes[Product] = (
  (JsPath \ "name").write[String] and
  (JsPath \ "description").write[String]
)(p => (p.name, p.description))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your last example is the way to go. Here's another way of doing the same thing using an implicit val instead of an implicit object:

```
implicit val productWrites: Writes[Product] = Writes { p =>
  Json.obj(
    "name" -> Json.toJson(p.name),
    "description" -> Json.toJson(p.description)
  )
}
```